# Why G-mail uses HTTPS in the address bar, why not SMTP

Tags: https, tcp, smtp

I am confused to see `https` (port 443) instead of **`SMTP`** in `https://gmail.com` or in fact any other e-mail services (web mails).
I herd and read that, `SMTP` protocol is used for e-mails. If I am correct, when exactly are these email systems use the `SMTP` protocol?.
Why can't I see the SMTP/S port on wireshark dump of my webmail?
Can the terms `WWW` and `Internet` be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

Because Gmail uses web interface. And there is no other alternative or option than http/s to interact with the mail servers. Also web interface does not fetch mails directly from the mail server. Rather it uses API provided by another server than mail to read or send e-mails.

If you use another mail client than Google’s web interface (Gmail) for e-mail, like Thunderbird, Outlook etc., then it requires SMTP/POP or IMAP protocol interface to get/ send emails.

HTTPS is a secured interface over HTTP to encrypt packets so there is nothing to do with e-mails I think its the primary reason why google uses HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

What you use in your browser is a web application. A front-end (a client) for the mail service.

*SMTP* is a protocol for sending mails. For retrieving there are other protocols like *POP3* or *IMAP*.

So when you open the service like Gmail basically you connect to a server hosting a front-end part. It in turn calls to underlying mail services like *IMAP* to show you your emails.

When you send the mail it calls underlying *SMTP* service.

If you need to configure your clients to connect directly to *SMTP/IMAP* infrastructure of Gmail you can use [this instruction](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en).